# supervisor gunicorn flask error

Tags: flask, gunicorn, supervisord

I have deploy my flask app with gunicorn, and when i use gunicorn to start my flask app ,it work fine. When i change to use supervisor to watch gunicorn, I can visit my web, but supervisor gives these logs:

```
2016-10-31 17:49:49,967 INFO supervisord started with pid 32949
2016-10-31 17:49:50,970 INFO spawned: 'vservice' with pid 32952
2016-10-31 17:49:51,971 INFO success: vservice entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-10-31 17:49:56,285 INFO exited: vservice (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-10-31 17:49:57,287 INFO spawned: 'vservice' with pid 32955
2016-10-31 17:49:58,289 INFO success: vservice entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-10-31 17:50:02,605 INFO exited: vservice (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-10-31 17:50:03,608 INFO spawned: 'vservice' with pid 32960
2016-10-31 17:50:04,609 INFO success: vservice entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2016-10-31 17:50:08,924 INFO exited: vservice (exit status 1; not expected)
2016-10-31 17:50:09,926 INFO spawned: 'vservice' with pid 32965
2016-10-31 17:50:10,927 INFO success: vservice entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

and supervisor stderrlog like this:

```
Error: Already running on PID 30874 (or pid file 'log/gunicorn.pid' is stale)
```

and here is my gunicorn config file:

```
import gevent.monkey
import multiprocessing

gevent.monkey.patch_all()

bind = '0.0.0.0:9000'

loglevel = 'error'
logfile = 'log/debug.log'
accesslog = 'log/access.log'
access_log_format = '%(h)s %(t)s %(U)s %(q)s'
errorlog = 'log/error.log'

pidfile = 'log/gunicorn.pid'

# number of processes
workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2 + 1
# number of threads of per process
threads = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
worker_class = 'gevent'
```

and here is my supervisor config file:

```
[program:vservice]
command=/data/server/venv/bin/gunicorn -c /data/server/gun.py manager:app
directory=/data/server/
stdout_logfile=/data/supervisor/log/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/data/supervisor/log/stderr.log
```

when i use gunicorn -c gun.py manager:app, my app works fine, but when i use supervisor to run it, it gives errors like above, and i can still visit my web and it seems like that my app works, but what is meaning of the errors given by supervisor? Does it have any bad effect on my deployment?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got an idea from here.
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/520#issuecomment-236301509

Try using a bash script to run gunicorn. Your supervisor config file should look like:

```
[program:vservice]
command=/path-to-bash-script/gunicorn.sh
directory=/data/server/
stdout_logfile=/data/supervisor/log/stdout.log
stderr_logfile=/data/supervisor/log/stderr.log
```

Set your `gunicorn.sh` to run the exec command for your gunicorn app

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /data/server/venv/bin/gunicorn -c /data/server/gun.py manager:app
```

And take away the line `pidfile = 'log/gunicorn.pid'` from your gunicorn config file.

It's because your bash script is what gets supervised, not gunicorn.